# How can I put a "div" over an Java Applet

Tags: javascript, css, applet

How can I put  a "div" over an Applet? 
is there any solution other than the famous "Hacks", is that there is nothing in HTML 5 that has solved this old problem? or anything else... :)

My "div" is below the Applets with the same z-index: 999;

**thank you**

Comment: Would you constitute a wrapper div styled as `position: relative;` and a nested div with `position:absolute;` and styled to overlay as a "hack"? e.g. `<div style="position:relative;"><applet /><div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:??px;height:??px;"></div></div>`

Comment: I don't see why using `position: absolute` to position an element over the applet wouldn't work, or why it would be considered a hack.

Comment: Haven't tried it with applet but maybe with an iframe. Had done this to show something over flash movie.

Comment: you can look at this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275953/how-to-display-div-over-a-java-applet-in-chrome