# Trying to make an iframe shim work with a CSS drop-down menu over a Java applet

Tags: java, html, css, iframe, applet

So, I have a page that runs a java applet generated through an external source.  I also have some source from another site I own, that uses CSS to create drop-down menus.  I am trying to implement the same drop-down style in my new java-applet-laden page.

The problem is, my menu is always layered underneath the java applet without regard for z-layers.  I think this is an "answered" issue here: [How to display <div> over a Java applet in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275953/how-to-display-div-over-a-java-applet-in-chrome).  However, the "solution" is a dead link.

I tried modifying the code here: http://midgetontoes.com/blog/2014/05/02/introduction-to-iframe-shim to fit my application.

My implementation fails on multiple levels.  First, whenever my shim/drop-down displays, it shifts the content of the entire page down 20-ish px.  Second, the drop down menu still disappears under the plugin.

Here are the relevant sections of code:

CSS:

```
.iframeshim-container {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

header ul.menu li.parent ul {
  background:url(dropdown_bg.png) 50% 0 repeat-x #98A2A9;
  display:none;
  left:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  position:absolute;
  top:1px;
  width:200px;
  z-index:100;
}

.iframeshim-container .content-container{
  display:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.iframeshim-container .shim-iframe{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -10000;

}

header ul.menu li.parent:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

header ul.menu li.parent:hover .iframeshim-container .shim-iframe {
  display: block;
}

header ul.menu li.parent:hover .iframeshim-container .content-container {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container maincontainer">
    <header class="clearfix">
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu" id="mainnav">
                <li><a href=".">Home</a></li>
                <li class="deeper parent"><a href="#">Test</a>
                    <div class="iframeshim-container">
                        <div class="content-container">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href=".">Item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/">Item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/">Item 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/">Item 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <iframe class="shim-iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>


    <section id="main" class="clearfix">
        <div id="content" class="clearfix" style="width: 910px;">
            <section id="maincontent">
                <APPLET CODE="myCode"></APPLET>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```